# How to inject spring resources into Apache Ignite classes?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, kotlin, ignite

I have a problem with injection spring beans into some ignite's classes. I'm trying to create this: Client -> Apache Ignite -> Spring-Data -> DataBase
Maybe it is wrong, i'm not sure.

So, at this moment my classes look like:
AppConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.ignite.cache"))
open class AppConfiguration : Serializable {
    private val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(AppConfiguration::class.java)

    @Bean
    open fun igniteInstance(): Ignite {
        val cfg = IgniteConfiguration()

        cfg.igniteInstanceName = "springDataNode"

        cfg.isPeerClassLoadingEnabled = true


        var clientCache: CacheConfiguration<Long, Client> = CacheConfiguration("ClientCache")
        clientCache.apply {
            setIndexedTypes(Long::class.java, Client::class.java)
            setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(ClientStore::class.java))
            isReadThrough = true
            isWriteThrough = true
        }

        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(clientCache)

        return Ignition.start(cfg)
    }
}
```

DataSourceConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("com.ignite.cache.model.repositories.springdatarepository"))
@EnableIgniteRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("com.ignite.cache.model.repositories.igniterepository"))
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.ignite.cache.model"))
open class DataSourceConfiguration : Serializable {

    @Bean
    open fun entityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        var entityManagerFactory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()

        entityManagerFactory.apply {
            dataSource = dataSource()
            setPackagesToScan("com.ignite.cache.model")

            var vendorAdapter: HibernateJpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()

            vendorAdapter.apply {
                setGenerateDdl(true)
                setShowSql(true)
            }

            var properties: Properties = Properties()

            properties.apply {
                put("database.dialet", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect")
                put("database.globally_quoted_identifiers", "false")
                put("database.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true")
                put("database.show_sql", "true")
            }

            jpaVendorAdapter = vendorAdapter
            setJpaProperties(properties)
        }

        return entityManagerFactory
    }

    @Bean
    open fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        var source: ComboPooledDataSource = ComboPooledDataSource()

        source.apply {
            driverClass = "org.postgresql.Driver"
            jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ignite"
            user = "postgres"
            password = "1111"
            acquireIncrement = 5
            idleConnectionTestPeriod = 60
            maxPoolSize = 20
            minPoolSize = 10
            initialPoolSize = 10
        }

        return source
    }

    @Bean
    open fun transactionManager() : PlatformTransactionManager {
        var manager: JpaTransactionManager = JpaTransactionManager()

        manager.apply {
            entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory().nativeEntityManagerFactory
        }

        return manager
    }

    @Bean
    open fun exceptionTranslator(): PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor = PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
data class Client
(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        var id: Long = 0,
        @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
        var email: String = "",
        @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
        var login: String = ""
) : Serializable
```

Repositories:

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "ClientCache")
interface IgniteClientRepository : IgniteRepository<Client, Long> {
}
@Repository
interface ClientRepository : CrudRepository<Client, Long>
```

Standart implemenation for service classes and CacheStore for ignite:

```
public class ClientStore implements CacheStore<Long, Client>, Serializable {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientStore.class);

    @SpringResource
    private IClientService clientRepository; // <- error is here (NPE)

    @Override
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, Client> igniteBiInClosure, @Nullable Object... objects) throws CacheLoaderException {
        Iterable<Client> clients = clientRepository.findAll();

        for(Client client : clients) {
            igniteBiInClosure.apply(client.getId(), client);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class);
        Ignite ignite = context.getBean(Ignite.class);

        (ignite.getOrCreateCache("ClientCache")).loadCache(null);

        IgniteClientRepository clientRepository = context.getBean(IgniteClientRepository.class);

        Iterable<Client> clients = clientRepository.findAll();
        for(Client client : clients) {
            logger.info(client);
        }

        logger.info("Finish");
    }
}
```

But when i try to load some data from database into cache i get error NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:486)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:217)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5439)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5488)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6103)
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1842)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1114)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1379)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:640)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:532)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:743)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:443)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:418)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:402)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.globalLoadCacheAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:3681)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.globalLoadCache(GridCacheAdapter.java:3657)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.loadCache(IgniteCacheProxy.java:387)
    at com.ignite.cache.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ignite.cache.model.service.ClientStore.loadCache(ClientStore.java:30)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:502)
    ... 26 more
```

I still can't figure out why my client service doesn't inject into CacheStore class. Maybe i should use xml config instead of java-class config for ignite?

Comment: you tagged the question with Java, but much of your code is not Java.

Comment: The line you indicate can't possibly throw a NPE. Which is line 22 of Main?

Comment: @JensSchauder yes, if was my fault. The prograaming language is kotlin and a few java. The 22th line in main is `(ignite.getOrCreateCache("ClientCache")).loadCache(null);` (another lines was commented and i deleted them, sorry for misleading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start Ignite using `Ignition#start` with `IgniteConfiguration` object, it's not aware of Spring context at all. You need to use `IgniteSpring#start` methods instead to provide context explicitly. Another option is to utilize [IgniteSpringBean](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSpringBean.html) that already implements `ApplicationContextAware` and starts `Ignite` instance properly.

Also note that you will need to provide either bean name or bean class as a parameter to `@SpringResource` annotation.

Comment: Thank you! I also figured out, that ignite doesn't know about spring context, but i don't know about IgniteSpring.start(...)!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ignite and I don't know the programming language you are using but it looks like Ignite and not Spring is creating your `ClientStore` instances. Therefore you need to inject the dependencies manually.

I'm not really familiar with the FactoryBuilder used there, so there might be nice solutions if you can use a constructor with arguments or even a lambda, but if that doesn' work, you can store a reference to the repository in static field and get it from there in the constructor of the `ClientStore`.

Comment: The problem is that ignite create own spring context and my app create another context too and when i try to inject ClientService into ClientStore the ignite's context doesn't see any implementation of it (that's all i figured out). When i create an xml config for ignite and declare beans there it works fine until i need ClientRepository which can't be created.